# VBA - run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)'

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, email-attachments

I am trying [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3bSuqRnQvA) to save separate sheets from one workbook as files and send those files as attachments in separate emails.

It's saving the files fine, but when it tries to email I get this "run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)': Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct."  Unfortunately I've been stuck on this error for a long time - any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

I have named the Splitcode range and that is working because the files go into the ActiveWorkbook folder.  I have the attachment names in column D of that sheet, exactly how they appear in the file. (see screenshot - [EmailAddress tab w/ Splitcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReIkt.png))

The ActiveWorkbook folder contains only the active workbook, until the macro is run and the files (Timecard-E1.xlsm , etc.) appear in there.

Here is the code:

```
Sub SaveAndSend()

Dim Splitcode As Range
Dim Path As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim email As Range
Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Splitcode = Range("Splitcode")

For Each cell In Splitcode
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Copy Before:=Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "\" & "Timecard-" & cell.Value, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next cell

For Each email In Sheets("EmailAddress").Range("B2:B5")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
         With OutMail
            .To = email.Value
            .Subject = Cells(email.Row, "D").Value
            .Body = "Hi " & Cells(email.Row, "C").Value & "," _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please review the attached timecard and let me know if approved." _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Thanks!"
            .Attachments.Add (Path & "\" & Cells(email.Row, "D").Value)
            '.Send
            .Save
        End With
Next email

End Sub
```

None of the other solutions I can find on line appear to be relevant to this specific problem.

Comment: What is the result of `Debug.Print Path & "\" & Cells(email.Row, "D").Value`? Is it what you expect? Side note, no parentheses: `.Attachments.Add Path & "\" & Cells(email.Row, "D").Value`. Best also to qualify the workbook/worksheet before any `Cells` calls.

Comment: This line doesn't make sense `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Copy Before:=Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)`. `Before` expects a Worksheet-Object of the Workbook you are copying to... not a new Worksheet

Comment: ^^^ `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Copy` is all you need - a new workbook will be created automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much, BigBen! Legend.

Comment: Tried with Debug.Print and it showed it was only picking up the file path, not file name.  So, I specified the workbook & sheet before the Cells call as you suggested and it worked!
Thanks again mate

Comment: At the risk of pushing my luck, does anyone know how to adjust this code to save the files as PDF instead of xlsm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigBen helped me solve this.  The issue was that the workbook and sheet were not qualified before the Cells call. Here is the working code:

```
Sub SaveAndSend()

Dim Splitcode As Range
Dim Path As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim email As Range
Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Splitcode = Range("Splitcode")

For Each cell In Splitcode
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Copy Before:=Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "\" & "Timecard-" & cell.Value, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next cell

For Each email In Sheets("EmailAddress").Range("B2:B5")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
         With OutMail
            .To = email.Value
            .Subject = Cells(email.Row, "D").Value
            .Body = "Hi " & Cells(email.Row, "C").Value & "," _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please review the attached timecard and let me know if approved." _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Thanks!"
            .Attachments.Add Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EmailAddress").Cells(email.Row, "D").Value
            '.Send
            .Save
        End With
Next email


End Sub
```

Thanks everyone!